# Error when trying to install open-cv on raspberry pi

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi

I've been trying to install open-cv on my raspberry pi 4 to have access to a webcam connected via USB using Python. When I run the command `pip install opencv-python` I get the following error

```
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for numpy
Failed to build numpy
ERROR: Could not build wheels for numpy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Can somebody help me solve this issue ?

So far, I've tried upgrading pip and also tried updating my wheels `pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel`.

Comment: You could try install the raspbian `python3-numpy` package first and see if that provides an appropriate version (`sudo apt update && sudo apt install python3-numpy`).

Comment: after executing this command, i tried using `pip install opencv-python` again. 
After that i got two new errors `Failed building wheels for numpy` and `Failed cleaning build dir for numpy`. I then got a final error saying `Can't roll back numpy; was not uninstalled ... `